# How to get numbers that have IE in case of data type float?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I work on sql server 2017 i face issue when save data on float data type it display as

```
IE
```

so how to get data only that display as IE on float data type

```
  CREATE TABLE #TestTable
         (
         Numbers float
         )
;
 INSERT INTO #TestTable
        (Numbers)
 VALUES  (0.0000001)
        ,(0.00001)
        ,(0.0000001)
        ,(0.00001)
        ,(0.0000001)
        ,(0.00001)
        ,(0.0000001)
        ,(0.00001)
        ,(10000000)
        ,(8)
        ,(1)
        ,(10000000)
        ,(14)
        ,(10000000)
        ,(1005)
```

Expected result

[image: get numbers float have ie]

**I try that but not convert IE why**

```
SELECT case when numbers like '%E-%' then cast(Numbers as numeric(37,15)) else cast(numbers as double precision) end as castedvalue FROM #TestTable
```

after run query above it not convert or show data for IE
AND it give me result below

```
castedvalue
1E-07
1E-05
1E-07
1E-05
1E-07
1E-05
1E-07
1E-05
10000000
8
1
10000000
14
10000000
1005
```

expected result after apply query above must be

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that in the query, since the formatting of data is done by the client application.

Or, to be more specific, you would need to tailor the query to your particular client application and how that application decides whether to use scientific notation or not.

As an example:

```
SELECT CAST(0.0002 AS float)
```

Above is formatting differently in MS's various tools:

SSMS:

```
0,0002
```

SQLCMD:

```
2.0000000000000001E-4
```

ADS:

```
0,0002
```

Say for instance that you use SSMS. Then you would have to determine the cut-off where SSMS uses scientific notation vs not. I.e., how large/small number do you have to have before it decided to use scientific notation. I doubt this is documented so you are in for trial and error. Based on that you can use those cut-off values in the WHERE clause. And, be aware that SSMS might change it formatting rules...

Answer (score 1):

First expected output:

```
SELECT Numbers FROM #TestTable WHERE Numbers < 1e0;
```

Second expected output:

```
SELECT FORMAT(Numbers, '0.########') FROM #TestTable;
```

Note this returns `nvarchar` using a [custom numeric format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings).

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=2ed26ae028e6639308de7d9ba77e57f5)

---

Your `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT case 
    WHEN numbers like '%E-%' then cast(Numbers as numeric(37,15)) 
    ELSE cast(numbers as double precision) end as castedvalue 
FROM #TestTable
```

...does not work as hoped because the result of the whole expression has to have a **single data type**. You are attempting to sometimes return a `numeric(37,15)` and other times `double precision` (a synonym of `float`).

SQL Server resolves the type incompatibility according to the rules of [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql). Since `float` has a higher precedence than `decimal`/`numeric`, the `numeric(37,15)` is implicitly converted to `float`. The result of the whole `CASE` expression is therefore `float`.

Note `numbers like '%E-%'` also contains incompatible types (`float` and `varchar`). This results in implicit conversion because the `LIKE` operator requires strings. The `float` column is converted to `varchar(23)`.